# Cant run apps fullscreen with wine

Tags: 12.10, wine, winetricks

I am running ubuntu 12.10 and when I am using wine 15. something then when I try to run world of warcraft on fullscreen, then the unity sidebar remains there. When i run league of legends, then it is not there. Maybe it is fault of wow not wine, but please try to help me somehow. and I have also checked Unredirect fullscreen windows on compizconfig settings manager.

Comment: I have the same problem with the GNOME-Shell, some (not all) games in wine show the GNOME-Shell at the top of the screen when in fullscreen mode. But this is not only a problem related to wine, as the flash player has the same issue on some sites when watching videos in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1):

When running a Wine application in fullscreen there may be issues from interference with the Unity desktop. In addition, fullscreen application will not benefit from Compiz.

We may therefore may want to consider to install [gnome-session-fallback](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) [image: Install gnome-session-fallback] and start a fallback GNOME session at login in case we plan to run a Wine fullscreen application.

Doing so has the following advantages:

- no interference from Unity dektop items (Launcher, Dash, HUD).
- All Unity key combinations are released for use in the Wine application.
- more CPU power is left for the application because we do not need to run Compiz.
- All our other applications are still available (through the *Applications* menu).